# How to lock tables in MS Access 2010?

Tags: ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007

I have a database with 10 tables in it.How to lock them and if someone tries to edit it should give warning message.

Answer (score 1):

Select *Properties* of the file, and set the mark for *Read-Only*.

Then nothing can be changed.